# Does Hilbert Transform commute with Function Multiplication modulo Compact on $L^p(R)$?

Tags: functional-analysis, lp-spaces, compact-operators, singular-integrals

Define Hilbert Transform (HT) as the convolution with the function $1/x$. E. Stein proves in his book 
**Singular Integrals and Differentiability Properties of Functions**
that HT, when understood as a singular integral operator, is a bounded operator on $L^p(\mathbb{R})$ for $p\in (1, \infty)$.

I am wondering if HT has compact commutator with multiplication by $C_0(\mathbb{R})$ on $L^p(\mathbb{R})$?

More precisely, if $T \in \mathscr{L}(L^p(\mathbb{R}))$ denotes the Hilbert transform, and $f \in C_0(\mathbb{R})$, is it true that $Tf - fT \in \mathbb{K}(L^p(\mathbb{R}))$? If it is true, would you please give me a reference? Thank you!

Comment: [Cross-posted to MathOverflow](http://mathoverflow.net/questions/157705/does-hilbert-transform-commute-with-function-multiplication-modulo-compact-on-l) within 30 hours of asking here. In the future, I suggest waiting a bit longer; and at any rate, include the link to the other post.

Comment: Dear user127096, thanks for your suggestion. I will bear that in mind in the future!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The commutator is compact if and only if $f$ is in [VMO](https://www.encyclopediaofmath.org/index.php/VMO-space). Source: [On the compactness of operators of Hankel type](http://dx.doi.org/10.2748/tmj/1178230105) by A. Uchiyama (free access; note that $VMO$ is called $CMO$ there). Since $C_0(\mathbb R)\subset VMO$, the answer to your question is positive.

Comment: Thank you for your references. I will read it it more details.

Comment: The proof to my question is contained on p.170 in the reference. Thanks!